# Distinguish variable and constant in #define macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, avr

I have macros like this:

```
#define _DDR_0  DDRD
#define _DDR_1  DDRD
#define _DDR_2  DDRD
// ....

#define _PN_0  0
#define _PN_1  1
#define _PN_2  2
// ...

/** Configure pin as output */
#define as_output(pin)   sbi(_DDR_##pin, _PN_##pin)
void    as_output_n(const uint8_t pin);
```

It is used like so:

```
as_output(2);

uint8_t b = 1;
as_output_n(b);
```

The `_n` variant is used for variables, the macro for constants (because it's much faster to do this with a macro).

Is there any possible way to make it so you can use `as_output` always, and depending on it being constant OR a variable, use the macro OR the function?

Answer (score 2):

Macros are expanded by the preprocessor which has no knowledge of what the code does. From the preprocessor's point of view all the macro arguments are simply tokens (with no logical meaning). In this case `as_output` macro is used to manufacture new code (via token pasting).

So, what you're trying to do, is not possible using just macros (there could be a way if `b` would be a macro itself, but i guess that's not what you're looking for).

You could use a const array for your `_DDR*` and `PN*` values, and an inline function instead of macros.

Comment: I suspected it's impossible, but it'd be nice (more intelligence for the preprocessor). It'd check if `pin` is numeric or not and that'd be enough to decide...